# CTE inside SQL IF-ELSE structure

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to do something like this

```
declare @a int=1
if (@a=1)
with cte as 
(
select UserEmail from UserTable 
)
else
with cte as
(
select UserID from UserTable
)
select * from cte
```

This is just the example, my actual query is far more complex. So I don't want to write the `SELECT` statement inside `IF` and `ELSE` statement twice after the CTE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If possible, find a way to avoid the `if` statement entirely.

E.g. in such a trivial example as in your question:

```
;with CTE as (
      select UserEmail from UserTable where @a = 1
      union all
      select UserID from UserTable where @a != 1 or @a is null
)
select /* single select statement here */
```

It should generally be possible to compose one or more distinct queries into a final `UNION ALL` cte, instead of using `if` - after all, both of the queries being combined must have compatible result sets anyway, for your original question to make sense.

Comment: a very nice workaround from Damien, using 'Union ALL' and adding the 'if' condition filter in the where clause.
For Performance, i suggest using the filter as the first clause in 'Where'

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, could you elaborate on why should we avoid `IF`, please?

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk - it's not an absolute prohibition, more a general guide - if you're trying to produce one result set, you should try to formulate how to produce that result set in a single query, and let the optimizer work out how best to produce it, rather than manually breaking that query up into chunks. As you can see from marc_s's answer, the alternative using `if` ends up with two queries with duplication between them.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that - the CTE **must** immediately be followed by exactly one SQL statement that can refer to it. You cannot split the "definition" of the CTE from the statement that uses it.

So you need to do it this way:

```
declare @a int=1

if (@a=1)
    with cte as 
    (
       select UserEmail from UserTable 
    )
    select * from cte

else

    with cte as
    (
       select UserID from UserTable
    )
    select * from cte
```

You cannot split the CTE "definition" for its usage (`select * from cte`)

Comment: @MartinSmith: I was afraid of that (but couldn't find a clear statement in the docs) :-( Thus removed my section. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I know CTE must immediatley followed by a sql statement. But i am looking for a way around. I don't want to write duplicated select statements.

Comment: @MegaMind: there **is no way around this** - it's the way the CTE's are defined to work.

Answer (score 4):

The `with cte (...) select from cte ...` is **a single statement**. Is not 'followed' by a statement, it **is** part of the statement. You are asking to split the statement in two which is obviously impossible.

As a general rule, SQL is a very unfriendly language for things like DRY and avoiding code repetition. Attempting to make code more maintainable, more readable, or simply trying to save a few keystrokes can (and usually does) result in serious runtime performance penalties (eg. attempting to move the CTE into a table value function UDF). The simplest thing would be to bite the bullet (this time, and in future...) and write the CTE twice. Sometimes it makes sense to materialize the CTE into a #temp table and then operate into on the #temp table, but only *sometimes*.

This [status-quo is unfortunate](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3179-you-only-get-one-chance-to-be-a-beginner), but is everything you can expect from [design by committee](http://www.ansi.org/)...